# Should the inherited class be in the same cs file of the base class?

Tags: inheritance, radix, derived-class, c#

I started to learn about inheritance and I was wondering where should I write the derived class. Should it be in the same .cs file as the base class or another .cs file? What is the consensus or norm about this? Does it even matter?

Comment: You should generally put each class (derived or not) in its own file.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I almost always put my derived class in a different files. But, if you use [inner class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twwxww86%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in your code, it's ok to be in the same file. The point is here, [`Single Responsibility Principle`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). By that;

- Reading your code takes less effort.
- You can simply check multiple classes in different windows at the same time.

Also check [`Multiple classes in a single .cs file - good or bad?`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53088/multiple-classes-in-a-single-cs-file-good-or-bad)

Comment: Soner, I have `BaseFunction : IFooable` and `Function<T> : BaseFunction`. The only reason I have a base class is to be able to put all `Function<T>` classes into a collection. Would you separate these into different files?

Answer (score 1):

You can do whatever you want, it doesn't matter.

In Java for example, the language allows you to put only one class in a file, and some programmers don't like it. In C# you can do whatever you feel comfortable.

Personally, I usually put the base class and the derived classes in one file, unless there is a big difference between them.

Comment: IMO, unless you're going for ultra portability (copying all the classes at once by copying one file) it seems like a travesty of encapsulation for your derived classes to live in the same file as your base class.

Comment: I just don't like when someone sends me lots of files which are actually very small. If you have one base class and two derived classes that overrides just 1-2 virtual functions, I prefer them in one file. 3 files is just a waste of tabs. If you have a lot of code in base class and derived class then OK split to different files is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where do you place it, your code will compile in both the cases. So you can organise them how do you want.

By speaking of good practices I think that you should put every class in a *.cs file* because it's more readable and manageable. Infact in long term it would be really hard to read and understand the code.

But remeber that if the class that you inherit from isn't in the same namespace of the base class you have to add the namespace to the section of using directives.

Comment: No, it is not even a *truism* that your derived classes should have the same namespace as your base class.   (not withstanding you might have to type a `using` statement!)

Comment: I got your point and I agree with you, but you misunderstood what I mean. Infact I said it just to highlight that if he doesn't put them in the same namespace he has to add a using directive. So I edited it.